# Can't import Angular2 bootstrap method

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to boot up basic Angular 2 (beta 2) app with TypeScript. I have the following `app.ts` file (copied from [Angular's latest setup guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html))

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
    template: `
        <div></div>
    `
})
class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

but when I try to compile it, I get error

> Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

If I instead use the format found on some other resources with `angular2/core` instead of `angular2/angular2` like

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/core';
```

I get error

> Error TS2305: Module '"node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.

What should I do to import all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *bootstrap*  was moved from `angular2/angular2` to `angular2/platform/browser` so you need to use it as

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

Answer (score 2):

As of `Angular2 alpha-53` list of imports has been changed from normal `angular2/angular2`

Since `Angular2 alpha-53` `bootstrap` can be imported from `angular2/platfrom/browser`.

Here is list of all imports may help to someone else.

```
import{Component,View,Directive,Input,Output,Inject,Injectable,provide,ElementRef} from 'angular2/core'; 

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import{CORE_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES,NgClass,NgIfNgForm,Control,ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

import{RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,Router,LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http'
```

Breaking change for import list
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha53-2015-12-13